# Como retornar null se não for encontrado nenhum resultado com find_by?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou obtendo um retorno como array (`[]`) de um escopo com `find_by` e desejo que o retorno seja vazio (`null`).

Veja abaixo alguns trechos do código:

```
class Dispute::Conference < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  belongs_to :dispute, counter_cache: true

  scope :scheduled, -> { find_by state: :scheduled }
  ...
end
```

É um relacionamento `has_many`, então é normal retornar um array caso não se encontrei nenhum resultado.

```
class Dispute < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :conferences, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end
```

Como estou utilizando um escopo, e espero somente um resultado do filtro, acreditei que retornasse `null` caso nenhum resultado fosse encontrado.

Existe alguma maneira de retornar `null`, para este caso específico?

Comment: Um detalhe importante, troquei `find_by` por `where`, por algum motivo que não sei explicar em alguns casos o retorno gera problemas com o `ActiveModel::Serializer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma que encontrei para resolver isso foi utilizando um `.present?` dentro de uma condicional no local onde faço a chamada do escopo `scheduled`:

```
class DisputeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  ...
  has_one :scheduled

  def scheduled
    Dispute::ScheduledSerializer.new object.conferences.scheduled if
      object.conferences.scheduled.present?
  end
end
```

Um detalhe é que se não fizer este tratamento um erro do `ActiveModel::Serializer` será apresentado.

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `read_attribute_for_serialization' for #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>>
```

Answer (score 1):

O `find_by` sempre retorna 1 ou `nil`. Como você trocou para `where`, retorna uma coleção ou vazio `[]`. Você pode utilizar

`def self.scheduled
  where(state: :scheduled).first
end`

para retornar o primeiro resultado ou `nil`.